# SELECT last Row for each Customer based on DateTime

Tags: sql, t-sql, databricks, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

I have an archive with master data. This table is updated once a week to store attributes for each customer.

```
Customer | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute n | DateTime
```

It happens that a customerID is removed from one week to the next one.

Now I would like to extract for each Customer (Distinct) the last row that has been populated in this table.

How would you do that with SQL?

Comment: _"Now I would like to extract for each Customer (Distinct) the last row that has been populated in this table."_ - how do you determine the "last populated row", exactly? SQL does not have any concept of records-on-disk or table-insertion-order or anything like that - if there isn't a column or expression that you can use then you're SOL.

Comment: I think the question has been addressed already, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

The basic idea is to group your records on `Customer`, then pick the max `DateTime`

Comment: Don't you need a trvial MAX with GROUP BY? SELECT
customer,
MAX(datecolumn)
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer; Can be simply used as subquery in case further columns should also be selected.

Comment: @Dai: Based on the last Column "DateTime".

Comment: So... `SELECT Customer, MAX( "DateTime" ) AS LatestDateTime FROM myTable GROUP BY Customer ORDER BY LatestDateTime;` ?

Comment: Which dbms? (The answer might be product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh: Databricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number() window funciton with common table expression to do that:

```
with cte as
(select customerID  , Attribute1 , Attribute2 , Attributen  , DateTime,
row_number()over(partition by customerID order by DateTime desc)rn
from customerArchive)
select customerID  , Attribute1 , Attribute2 , Attributen  , DateTime from cte where rn=1
```

If an extra column named `rn` is not a problem you can use `*`

```
with cte as
(select *,row_number()over(partition by customerID order by DateTime desc)rn
from customerArchive)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Or you can again join the cte with customer table. It will only work if you don't have any duplicate record for a given DateTime. It will be slower

```
    with cte as
            (select *,row_number()over(partition by customerID order by DateTime desc)rn
            from customerArchive)
            select Customer.* from cte inner join Customer 
            on Customer.customerID=cte.customerID and Customer.DateTime=cte.DateTime
            where rn=1
```

*** As @nbk pointed out it’s never wise to use `*`. Mentioning column names might take some time but it will be much safer option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since the table contains like 150 columns > Any way to simplify the SELECT part? I would like to not name every column

Comment: not naming the column is bad style and not recommended